# NextJS deployed to Vercel: 404 page not found

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have a NextJS app without an integrated api that I want to deploy to Vercel. It works fine when I run it locally `yarn run dev` and I can also build it `yarn run build` without any errors. When I deploy it Vercel, however, I receive a `404 Error`.

Here is my folder structure:

```
app/
  - components
  - pages
    - editor
      - [id].tsx
    ...tsx
  - public
  - utils
    - db
      api.ts
```

I am using NextJs 10.0.3.

Here is a link to the deployed [app](https://clubhouse-bio-2qgg4rvij.vercel.app).

I don't have a nextjs config file. My assumption is that the error is caused by the dynamic route but I can't find my mistake. Also, no page is working when the app is deployed as opposed to only the dynamic page.

Do you have pointers on where to look next?

EDIT 1:
[Here](https://github.com/JanRuettinger/ClubhouseBio) is a link to the GitHub repo.

EDIT 2:
I found an issue but don't know how to fix it.

This is how my build output looks like on Vercel:
[image]

This is how it's supposed to look like on Vercel:
[image]

Not sure why the whole `_next` folder is missing.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Go to Project Settings

Change Framework preset from `Other` to `Next.js`

Redeploy the project.

Comment: 1) Change Framework preset: go to the project page -> settings tab -> Build & Development Settings -> Change Framework preset from Other to Next.js

2) re-deploy: The Deployments tab lists all the previously deployed builds. Click the vertical ellipsis (⋮) icon where you will find the option to Redeploy that specific build once again

Comment: weird solution but this worked for me. I had to actually select Other and then select Next again.

Answer (score 32):

I just had this exact same issue.
I have my Next app in a sub directory. I think that might be the cause of some problems.

What worked for me was.

- Make sure to pick the right sub directory. Mine had a little Next Js icon on it.
- The framework preset needs to be set to Next.js.

Comment: Worked for me! Updated the 'Root Directory' of my project on Vercel and it worked again.

Comment: try removing vercel.json if thats is an issue, https://github.com/t3-oss/create-t3-app/issues/912

Comment: This was helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Edited

Try to deploy using
`now --prod --force`
The `--force` flag will clear your build cache (in production) and force production push.
If still no working then make sure to add now.json

Comment: I am using the Vercel Github integration for deployment. I think it builds it from scratch every time I deploy. I have just compared it with other projects which I have deployed successfully and with them I didn't provide a now.json. So I doubt it's necessary.

Comment: @siva try by adding now.json. Here is a little help => https://docs-git-update-lambda-serverless-function.zeit.now.sh/docs/v2/advanced/configuration/

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure to choose Next.js as Framework preset (and not other). You can find that in Project settings and under Build & Development Settings.
More here: https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/build-step

Comment: This is what caused it for me - not sure why it changed from Next.js but it did.

Answer (score 3):

Redeployed it with choosing nextjs as framework

Answer (score 2):

[video reference codegrepper](https://www.grepper.com/answers/683282/i+got+404+not+found+in+vercel+after+deployment+but+it+work+in+localhost?ucard=1).

1)go to the project. then settings => click general tab => at build and development settings=>
choose next.js from others in the framework preset

2)again redeploy the project

3)It will work

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I first attempted to deploy Vercel through a team. When I created a new Vercel project under my individual Vercel account and deployed the same code, it worked! I hope this saves someone else time because I just lost 3 hours trying to find this. I'm using Next.js as well.

If you are trying to deploy through a team, you might need to configure the team ID in your vercel.json first e.g.

```
{
  "currentTeam": "team_ofwUZockJlL53hINUGCc1ONW"
}
```

ref: https://vercel.com/docs/configuration#global/config-json/current-team

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My bug was this: [Cannot destructure property 'store' of 'useReduxContext(...)' as it is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75474365/cannot-destructure-property-store-of-usereduxcontext-as-it-is-null/76072998#76072998)

If you are using redux, make sure your store provide is on the pages/_app.js level, not in the pages/index.js file, like this:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import '../assert/css/master.scss';
import store from '../store/store';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try and change your file with jsx to js it solve my own issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, if all the solution above didnt work. You can try to do redeploy but try to change the check on "Use existing Build Cache".

In my case, i have a 404 Page Not Found issues only on naked domain (it works fine on www domain), then I try redeploy with checking "Use existing Build Cache", and it solved