# Vercel custom domain returning: Not Found - Request ID:

Tags: next.js, http-status-code-404, vercel

TL;DR: I have a next js website that is working on all vercel domains (production, and preview domains). When I try to use a custom domain they return a page that looks like the screenshot below:
[image]

- Vercel domain: https://tasmto.vercel.app/
- Custom domain: http://www.tasmto.com/
- GH repo: https://github.com/tasmto/portfolio/

---

The site is in a subfolder named web but I have already configured that on vercel and I've made sure Next.js is the selected framework.

[image]

---

What I've tried so far:

- Pointing the domain through an A-record and using nameservers.
- Deleting the entire vercel project and trying again.
- Pointing a subdomain to the app instead off myt apex domain.
- Redeploying the app.

The site works when I use 100% Netlify but for some reason Vercel just doesn't want to serve an already working site to my domain and I am stump'd.

---

Thank you so much in advance (any advice or ideas will help).

*PS: I know variations of this questions have been asked but either I'm too dense to apply the solutions or I've misconfigured something else somewhere.*

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after sleeping on it here is what finally worked for me.

1. (Optional) I added a now.json with the contents below.
2. Because I was using the nameserver option I went into the domain settings inside of vercel and added the pre-existing A record again (as if I wasn't using the nameservers at all.

[image]

Now.json contents:

```
{
    "name": "portfolio",
    "alias": [
        "tasmto.com",
        "www.tasmto.com"
    ]
}
```

If this doesn't fix it have a look at **[this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65771294/nextjs-deployed-to-vercel-404-page-not-found)**.

Comment: This doesn't work bro.