# Next.js Deployed to Vercel returns a 404 not found

Tags: next.js, vercel, custom-error-pages

I'm trying to deploy a Next.js app to Vercel, it's a portfolio with only one page(index) and a couple of API routes. Vercel dashboard displays that the deployment is successful but when I visit the app it displays the layout component(the navbar and the footer but some styles are lost) with a 404 page like the attached image[image: here]. I tried to deploy with getStaticProps and with getServerSideProps and ended up with the same result. The API routes are working fine though both in SSG and SSR, I can retrieve the data from them weather from the browser or postman for example. I've been searching for a while now and this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65771294/nextjs-deployed-to-vercel-404-page-not-found) is the most relative one to mine, but I tried all solution mentioned in it and non of them worked for me. I made sure that the framework preset is next.js and that the root directory is correct, the app isn't served through a sub directory. Also I'm using a variable for the domain name stored in the .env file, I tried to deploy and leave it as the default(localhost:3000) and tried to change it to on of the vercel auto assigned domain names and tried to add the variable from the project settings on vercel, and also tried to deploy without it at all and all the scenarios leaded to the same result(the 404 page and the APIs are working fine). This is the first time I deploy on vercel, I tried to contact them but I received no answers, I guess because I'm on a hobby tier. This is the project [repo](https://github.com/KareemAbbas1/new-portfolio). The app works fine in development and also when I build and start the server locally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NextJS deployed to Vercel: 404 page not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65771294/nextjs-deployed-to-vercel-404-page-not-found)

Comment: No it didn't but it's the most relative issue to mine. I tried all the solutions mentioned in it, but non of them worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're calling internal endpoints (e.g. functions on `api` folder) in `getStaticProps`. This is a Next.js anti-pattern (More about this on the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props#write-server-side-code-directly)). The reason being is that `getStaticProps` fetches the necessary data required to build the static page on build-time, but at this point of the process, the serverless functions contained on the `api` folder have not been deployed yet. You're getting a 404 page because you are using a `try/catch` block in `getStaticProps`, so when `axios` throws, `catch` block takes the control and returns `notFound: true`.

Comment: Thank for this clarification. I'm not how relevant this is, but I also tried to deploy using getServerSideProps and ended up with the same result(404). Also, I'm new to Next.js so if you could provide me with a work around I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: From what I can see, both `projects` and `skills` endpoints return static data, so it's not clear to me why you're using api endpoints for this. Can you try just returning this data directly from `getStaticProps` as the docs suggest and see if that works? Other than that, I don't see any other issue.

Comment: Also, as a side note, I don't even see the necessity to use `getStaticProps` for this since this is just static data.