# Cannot destructure property 'store' of 'useReduxContext(...)' as it is null

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, redux-toolkit, next.js13

Im using NextJs 13 and redux toolkit.

When i try the `npm run build` command, i get this error:
**Cannot destructure property 'store' of 'useReduxContext(...)' as it is null.**

I think this has something to do with **useAppSelector**, am i getting the state right?

**This is the page component:**

```
"use client";

import React from "react";
import { useAppSelector } from "../../redux/hooks";

export default function HomePage() {
  const user = useAppSelector((state) => state.user);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**This is the *store.ts* file:**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { userSlice } from './reducers/reducers';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userSlice.reducer,
  },
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

**This is the *hooks.ts* file:**

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import type { TypedUseSelectorHook } from 'react-redux'
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store'

export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```

**And this is the *reducers.ts* file:**

```
import { RootState } from "./../store";
import { PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export interface userPayload {
  id: number,
  guest: boolean,
  username: string,
  email: string,
  income: number,
  limit: number,
}

const initialUserState = {
  id: 0,
  guest: false,
  username: "",
  email: "",
  income: 0,
  limit: 0,
};

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: initialUserState,
  reducers: {
    inputData: (state, action: PayloadAction<userPayload>) => {
      (state.income = action.payload.income), (state.limit = action.payload.limit);
    },
    inputAuth: (state, action: PayloadAction<userPayload>) => {
      (state.id = action.payload.id),
        (state.guest = action.payload.guest),
        (state.username = action.payload.username),
        (state.email = action.payload.email);
    },
  },
  
});

export const { inputData, inputAuth } = userSlice.actions

export const selectCount = (state: RootState) => state.user

export default userSlice.reducer
```

Comment: In the `hooks.ts` file try not to import the types, but the classes. Like `import { TypedUseSelectorHook } from 'react-redux'` and the same for the imports from `store.ts`

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code provided where you setup your store and redux Provider. If these are missing it would explain your error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue, my friend. Move the store provider into the **pages/_app.js** file (Instead of the **pages/index.js** file), and it should work. Here is what I did:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import '../assert/css/master.scss';
import store from '../store/store';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i did. Brian commented the solution already, but i'm marking this as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the errors when deploying an application to KUBERNETES using DOCKERFILE:

- TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'store' of 'useReduxContext(...)' as it is null.
- TypeError: (0 , g.useAppDispatch) is not a function
- and so on.

*(NEXT 13, Redux ToolKit, Dockerfile and FSD were used)*

In my case, I used Feature Sliced Disign and I had two PAGES folders: inside and outside the SRC folder.

The problem was solved after renaming the SRC/PAGES folder to something else (in my case SRC/WINDOWS).

[error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WgWk.png)

[folders before fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Czv9.png)

[folders after fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXNDs.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. To solve this I simply renamed the folder that named the pages in my project

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).