# NextJS 13 - 404 This page could not be found

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel

I'm using the last version of nextJS (13.3) and have a fairly simple routing as follows.

```
- app
-- blog
--- [post]
```

The following route works perfectly in the local environment: `http://localhost:3000/blog/just-a-blog-post`.
But deploying on Vercel gives me the following error: `This page could not be found`.
the build to Vercel was successful, the home page works fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NextJS deployed to Vercel: 404 page not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65771294/nextjs-deployed-to-vercel-404-page-not-found)

Comment: @eten, actually I tried the answers there but no help. the preset is already set to Next.js and since the next is installed in the root directory, Don't think I need to set any root directory in Vercel. Ah and by the way all routes work fine, only the dynamic ones ([post])

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?  I have an similar issue!

Comment: I'm using NextJS 13.4.4 and have just solved this problem in my project. My app 
 already has files in the `/pages` directory (which are working fine). After creating my first `/app` route, the new (dynamic) route returns a 404 Page Not Found. I had to add a new – non-dynamic – page to the `/app` directory and I also had to remove the `i18n` section from my next.config.js file.

Comment: yes the i18n section is used with the pages router, with app router you must not put it