# Node modules not importing when using Vercel

Tags: javascript, node-modules, vercel

I have a web application, and I need to use node modules. I am using Vercel to to host it. It is a personal project of one page. I have had no troubles except for when importing modules in a .js file.

```
import { process } from './node_modules/process';
```

I have tried these other ways to import it:

- Using `require('node_module')`.
- Turning the `.js` file into a `.mjs` file.
- Adding `type='module'` into the relevant script tag.
- Using a separate `.mjs` file and importing the there then exporting and importing into the main `.js` file.

The way I have it currently is the way I would expect it to work normally; however, I get this error when importing:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eULvO.png)

I looked into GitHub Pages/Vercel issues with node, but nothing was relevant.

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVTN4.png)

Comment: Then see: [NextJS deployed to Vercel: 404 page not found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72238277/22152755). Change the framework, to whatever your is.

Comment: I have tried that - I'm not using any framework, just JS, HTML, CSS and npm, so that throws an error about not finding Next.js specific pages, such as there being no app or pages directory. Any way around this or do I need to switch to a Next.js framework?

Comment: So, you set "framework" to "other" in Vercel?

Comment: It was originally. Link you gave said to change to Next.js, but I have tried that :)

Comment: But when setting to "other", it shouldn't mention anything about Next.js, that's correct, and you only see the error mentioned in your question?

Comment: Yes? Not quite sure what you're asking but yeah the error only happens on the other framework. Using Next.js famework it simply doesn't deploy.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out that, also include your `vercel.json` file in your question that should include some configuration. Also, all your files are in the root?

Comment: All my files are in root - see updated question for file structure. I don't have a vercel.json file that I can see - I am using Vercel to deploy a GitHub project so I didn't think I needed one if that helps?

Comment: I got a bit confused here, what do you mean by uploading a "GitHub" project to Vercel? Isn't your project just HTML, CSS, JS, and some npm modules (`node_modules` folder), I'm not sure of the *exact* term, but I think it's called a Node.js project therefore "GitHub" isn't involved anywhere? Also, yes `vercel.json` file is needed? How do you think Vercel is going to know the starting file of your project? Guessing? I don't think so :-) See: [Configuring Projects with vercel.json](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/project-configuration)

Comment: I followed this: https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/git/vercel-for-github. My project works fine, except when I try to import node modules. Never had any need for a vercel.json file, and can't find any info in Vercels docs of how to set one up, aside from it telling you what it does, so I assume if you needed it it would be added during deployment.

Comment: You uploaded a GitHub Repository to Vercel, OK; I still think you need `vercel.json` file, when run your project locally, do you need to run any commands manually `npm run start`? Also what's your starting directory, `index.html`? And, show how you import them (post your `index.html` file - or whatever file causing the error).

Comment: No no commands, I simply commit and push to update it. Starting directory is index.html yes, and I have imported the modules using npm. The code above shows the error. Since I can't chat, would you like to post an answer with a solution you are thinking of, if you have one, so that we can stop flooding the comments? Gotta obey the law and all that

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.